# Role based entity framework model validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is it possible to validate model of an entity, that is going to be saved to db, based on the role the user that saves the entity has? For example one user has Role1 other Role2. Role1 can change all of the properties, whereas Role2 just some of them. My model implements IValidatableObject and I was wondering if I could validate sent model in the public IEnumerable Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) method.